# Understanding a functor instance of my custom data type

Tags: haskell, functor

I have this data type:

```
data Arf a = Ser a [Arf a] deriving Show
```

When instantiating `Functor` this code works:

```
instance Functor Arf where
    fmap f [] = []
    fmap f (Ser x xs) = Ser (f x) (map (fmap f) x)
```

Why is `(map (fmap f) x)` used instead of `(fmap f x)` in the second argument to `Ser`?

Comment: Unfortunately your code does not work. In fact `fmap f [] = []` will throw an error instead (in addition to the error pointed out by Fyodor Soikin). Please click on [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69262905/edit) and update your question.

Comment: You can see how ghc writes the `Functor` instance by running `:set -XDeriveFunctor -ddump-deriv` in ghci and then `data Arf a = Ser a [Arf a] deriving Functor`

Comment: `fmap f []` is entirely extraneous in addition to not type checking. There is only one constructor (`Ser`) for `Arf`, so only one case to define. There *is* no "empty" `Arf a` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a typo in your code: at the very end of the last line, it should be `xs` instead of `x`.

With that out of the way, let's discuss the maps.

The inner `fmap` maps the function `f` over the `Arf a` type. So you might observe that in this case:

```
     f ::     a ->     b
fmap f :: Arf a -> Arf b
```

But those `Arf a` values are in a list! So how do you apply a function that transforms a *single* `Arf a` value to a whole *list* of those values, transforming each of them? With `map`, of course!

So the outer `map` applies to the whole list:

```
          f ::       a  ->      b
     fmap f ::   Arf a  ->  Arf b
map (fmap f) :: [Arf a] -> [Arf b]
```

Answer (score 1):

(Fixing as per Fyodor's comment...)

> Why is `(map (fmap f) xs)` used instead of `(fmap f xs)` in the second argument to `Ser`?

What is the second argument to `Ser`? It's a `[Arf a]`, i.e. a list of `Arf`s.

How do you apply `f` to the elements in the `xs` list? You do `map ??? xs`...

But what is the `???` function?

Well, you want it to apply `f` to the inside those `Arf`s, so you need it to call recursively the same `fmap` function that you are defining, hence `??? === fmap f`.

Therefore `map (fmap f) xs`.